# Config testlink with LDAP is not working

Tags: ubuntu, active-directory

I am new to LDAP configuration and I have set my testlink in my Ubuntu machine . It works fine with its own DB User . Then I start to config it with company's LDAP and meet some issue . Here are my steps and related settings :

1. I have use a LDAP browser and have connected to LDAP sever and it works fine. 
   Please see the screenshot below : http://y.photo.qq.com/img?s=klzAHez1w&l=y.jpg
2. according to others experience , created some user info (name , email etc.) in testlink's own DB. please refer to : https://blog.frogslayer.com/get-testlink-working-with-ldap-authentication/
3. then config testlink's config as below screenshot : 
   http://y.photo.qq.com/img?s=Xknw7SLlw&l=y.jpg

All I need is use user name &password from LDAP for testlink login .

I have tried some user name and does not work. Login page always show error "error user and password". Only users from testlink's own DB can login successfully . I do not how to do. Is there any one can help me ?thanks very much .

Comment: HI all，  from testlink forum's post , I have created a new test php file to test LDAP bind . It works fine and based on that I modify  my  testlink config to be as bleow :http://y.photo.qq.com/img?s=H0GEIbIMz&l=y.jpg. But testlink still show the error and indicate I have imput wrong name &pwd  which are complete right . Please help

Answer (score 1):

For those like me trying to make it work with version 1.9.16+, take a look at the [new documentation here](https://github.com/TestLinkOpenSourceTRMS/testlink-code) handling multiple ldap :

```
$tlCfg->authentication['ldap'][1]['ldap_server'] = 'ldap.xyz.com';
$tlCfg->authentication['ldap'][1]['ldap_port'] = '389';
...
```

srsly... who makes this kind of change without a version increment?

Answer (score 0):

finally I got a answer from testlink mantis syterm : http://mantis.testlink.org/view.php?id=7713  , so I change the  $tlCfg->authentication to $tlCfg->authentication['ldap'][1].  It works!  Yee~~~